# ¿Tiene alguna ventaja usar Bokeh (sobre Plotly) en algunas cuestiones particulares?

Tags: plotly, bokeh

Bokeh se presenta como una biblioteca que permite presentar graficas animadas o interactivas. Veo que La biblioteca Plotly ofrece la misma posibilidad. Mi pregunta es, entonces, que ventajas tiene una de las bibliotecas sobre la otra? ¿Sirven, acaso, para aplicaciones diferentes?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema que presentas?